# Unable to include header file in C++ console application project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files, visual-c++-2010

I have been trying linking of a .lib file and also including a header file in my C++ console application project. I copied the C++ header file from one of my other projects, and pasted it under `Header Files` folder in console application project. Here's the screenshot to see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4cK.png

However, when I try to include the header in my code as `#include...`, I do not get an intellisense with my header file's name. (I only see targetver.h, stdafx.h and Debug folder)
I tried to point `Add additional include directories` in my C++ console application project properties to the Project folder itself, but that doesn't seem to help and the file still doesn't show up.

If I write the name of the header file as `#include "DllTest.h"`, I get an error saying:
  `Cannot open include file: 'DLLTest.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\ht\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\dlltest\dlltestconsole\dlltestconsole.cpp`

How is the header file included in here, so that it starts appearing? If I `add a new item > Header File`, name it to DLLTest.h and copy paste the header files content here, it just shows up normally. How will the header file which is copied - pasted into `Header Files` folder show up in the code?

Comment: Is "DllTest.h" at your project's directory? (For example near dlltestconsole.cpp?)

Comment: @phantasmagoria : It's in the `Header Files` under the project. Here's the screenshot to see: http://i.imgur.com/JFFIn.png

Comment: Yes, but where is the file on disk?  The "Header Files" is not really a folder, it's a _filter_ that is used for organization in the UI only.  A file from anywhere on disk can be added to that filter.  The compiler knows nothing about filters, it only knows about locations on disk.  You'll need to make sure that the folder in which it is located is present in the "Additional Include Directories."

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Thank you very much! Infact that would have qualified as my answer. However, I also wanted to ask how do I copy paste these these files in my project so that they come in project directory itself (the way I can do in C# projects). Do I have to manually copy in the project directory and then Add Existing Item -> Select from the project direcotry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ projects, the things that look like folders in the Solution Explorer aren't actually folders, they are *filters*.  They are UI-only entities that can be used to organize project items in the IDE.  They do not in any way reflect the structure or location of items on disk, though.  You can add a file from any location on disk to any filter in the solution.

The compiler knows nothing of these filters; it only knows about files as they exist on disk.

In your case, the files are not located in your project folder.  You'll either need to:

- copy your files into your project folder, then add them to the project from there (right-click on the solution then Add Existing Item), or
- add the files from where they are, then add their location to the "Additional Include Directories" property in the project properties.

I do not know of any way to have the IDE automatically move files to the project directory when you copy and paste them into the project.  The C++ project system is fundamentally different from the project system used for C# and VB.

Comment: I like the note that "C++ project is fundamentally different from C#".